# Send variables with onclick action

Tags: forms, onclick

I want to send my variables with the onclick event, when the users clicks on the image.

Netbeans says following error message:

> unreported exception java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException; must
>   be caught or      declared to be thrown

Here is the code:

```
 HTMLCode+="<td width='40' style='border:1px solid #99a1ba' align='center'><img     src='../images/";
 HTMLCode+="empty.png'</td>";
 HTMLCode+="onclick=\"window.open('availability.jsp?";
 HTMLCode+=TMAXSSProtect.encrypt("user="+person.getPersonID()+"&clickeddate="+today2.get(Calendar.DATE))+"','_self')\"></td>";


 today2.add(today2.DATE, 1);
 HTMLCode+="</td>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to code a "try catch" around your code. Maybe this helps

Comment: or you change the end of your function 'throws InvalidKeySpecException' to this: 'throws SQLException {'